# Saxon c# XSLT XDM node not build

Tags: c#, xslt-2.0, saxon

Here I need to pass the xml as a parameter to XSLT. So I try to ass the stringXML toXDM node I am getting nullprointerexception. Below is my code and input stringxml.

Could any one please help me on this.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        JobDTO jobDTO = null; //DB bean class

       Processor m_saxon = null;
       XdmNode d = null;
       using (DBManager db = new DBManager())// connecting to DB
       {
           string m_jobId ="59d0ae8e-b03a-4d0e-a2c2-3f048375f759"; //DB primary key cloumn value
           jobDTO = db.GetJob(m_jobId); //getting row from DB
           using (XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(jobDTO.JobXml))) //job.JobXml have the stringxml value
           {
            d = m_saxon.NewDocumentBuilder().Build(xr);//here getting null pointer exception.because of xr is None
           }
        }
    }
}
```

}

stringXML is as below

```
<renderItem processItem="true">
  <callerid      xmlns="http://services.lexisnexis.com/shared/xmlschema/servicescommon/2">0</callerid>
  <coredataitem xmlns="http://services.lexisnexis.com/shared/xmlschema/coredataitem/2">
    <status>
      <statusvalue>Success</statusvalue>
    </status>
    <itemtype>document</itemtype>
    <title>doclist</title>
    <coredataitemdetail group="Renderer">
      <detailname xmlns="http://services.lexisnexis.com/shared/xmlschema/servicescommon/2">pageCount</detailname>
      <detailvalue xmlns="http://services.lexisnexis.com/shared/xmlschema/servicescommon/2">1</detailvalue>
    </coredataitemdetail>
    <coredataitemdetail group="Renderer">
      <detailname xmlns="http://services.lexisnexis.com/shared/xmlschema/servicescommon/2">statusMessage</detailname>
    </coredataitemdetail>
    <coredataitemdetail group="Renderer">
      <detailname xmlns="http://services.lexisnexis.com/shared/xmlschema/servicescommon/2">subItemsShouldMerge</detailname>
    </coredataitemdetail>
    <coredataitemdetail group="Renderer">
      <detailname xmlns="http://services.lexisnexis.com/shared/xmlschema/servicescommon/2">subitemsAreIndependent</detailname>
    </coredataitemdetail>
    <coredataitemdetail group="Renderer">
      <detailname xmlns="http://services.lexisnexis.com/shared/xmlschema/servicescommon/2">rendertype</detailname>
      <detailvalue xmlns="http://services.lexisnexis.com/shared/xmlschema/servicescommon/2">XPP</detailvalue>
    </coredataitemdetail>
    <coredataitemdetail group="Renderer">
      <detailname xmlns="http://services.lexisnexis.com/shared/xmlschema/servicescommon/2">ssafailedstatuscode</detailname>
      <detailvalue xmlns="http://services.lexisnexis.com/shared/xmlschema/servicescommon/2">0</detailvalue>
    </coredataitemdetail>
    <coredataitemdetail group="Renderer">
      <detailname xmlns="http://services.lexisnexis.com/shared/xmlschema/servicescommon/2">ssadownloadtime</detailname>
      <detailvalue xmlns="http://services.lexisnexis.com/shared/xmlschema/servicescommon/2">0</detailvalue>
    </coredataitemdetail>
    <coredataitemdetail group="Renderer">
      <detailname xmlns="http://services.lexisnexis.com/shared/xmlschema/servicescommon/2">ssauploadtime</detailname>
      <detailvalue xmlns="http://services.lexisnexis.com/shared/xmlschema/servicescommon/2">0</detailvalue>
    </coredataitemdetail>
    <coredataitemdetail group="Renderer">
      <detailname xmlns="http://services.lexisnexis.com/shared/xmlschema/servicescommon/2">apollodownloadtime</detailname>
      <detailvalue xmlns="http://services.lexisnexis.com/shared/xmlschema/servicescommon/2">0</detailvalue>
    </coredataitemdetail>
    <coredataitemdetail group="Renderer">
      <detailname xmlns="http://services.lexisnexis.com/shared/xmlschema/servicescommon/2">apolloitemcount</detailname>
      <detailvalue xmlns="http://services.lexisnexis.com/shared/xmlschema/servicescommon/2">0</detailvalue>
    </coredataitemdetail>
    <coredataitemdetail group="Renderer">
      <detailname xmlns="http://services.lexisnexis.com/shared/xmlschema/servicescommon/2">preprocessingtime</detailname>
      <detailvalue xmlns="http://services.lexisnexis.com/shared/xmlschema/servicescommon/2">1</detailvalue>
    </coredataitemdetail>
    <coredataitemdetail group="Renderer">
      <detailname xmlns="http://services.lexisnexis.com/shared/xmlschema/servicescommon/2">renderingtime</detailname>
      <detailvalue xmlns="http://services.lexisnexis.com/shared/xmlschema/servicescommon/2">2823</detailvalue>
    </coredataitemdetail>
    <coredataitemdetail group="Renderer">
      <detailname xmlns="http://services.lexisnexis.com/shared/xmlschema/servicescommon/2">totalprocessingtime</detailname>
      <detailvalue xmlns="http://services.lexisnexis.com/shared/xmlschema/servicescommon/2">2824</detailvalue>
    </coredataitemdetail>
    <coredataitemdetail group="Renderer">
      <detailname xmlns="http://services.lexisnexis.com/shared/xmlschema/servicescommon/2">processed</detailname>
      <detailvalue xmlns="http://services.lexisnexis.com/shared/xmlschema/servicescommon/2">yes</detailvalue>
    </coredataitemdetail>
    <coredataitemdetail group="Renderer">
      <detailname xmlns="http://services.lexisnexis.com/shared/xmlschema/servicescommon/2">xhtmlCreationTime</detailname>
      <detailvalue xmlns="http://services.lexisnexis.com/shared/xmlschema/servicescommon/2">99</detailvalue>
    </coredataitemdetail>
    <coredataitemdetail group="Renderer">
      <detailname xmlns="http://services.lexisnexis.com/shared/xmlschema/servicescommon/2">ssastatuscode</detailname>
      <detailvalue xmlns="http://services.lexisnexis.com/shared/xmlschema/servicescommon/2">0</detailvalue>
    </coredataitemdetail>
  </coredataitem>
</renderItem>
```

Comment: Consider to post the exact error message you get, a stack trace is even better. Are you using `XdmNode d` anywhere at all? Where is `m_saxon` declared and initialized?

Comment: Error :  at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)

Comment: I have declared m_saxon is a instance variable. Processor m_saxon = null;

Comment: XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(stringXML)), I am always getting xr values as none.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the assignment `XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(stringXML))`. Consider to post a minimal but complete sample allowing us to reproduce the problem. If that line really gives an error then it has nothing to do with Saxon or XSLT 2.0 as that line does not use any Saxon classes or APIs.

Comment: But getting None it is giving null pointer exception.

Comment: As I said, post a minimal but complete sample allowing others to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have edited and posted entire my console application. Could you look on this?

Comment: Why is `Processor m_saxon = null;` assigned `null` and then nowhere initialized as `new Processor()`?

Comment: Yaa got it, Problem resolved. Thanks yaar. I didn't intialized.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, Martin Honnen identified the solution: your variable holding the Saxon Processor is unitialized.